# DataLake Power BI Design Pattern

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2

Our customer has a common problem of many distributed datastores with varying technology stacks. Then end game is to bring certain parts of data together to produce detailed reporting through Microsoft Power BI.

Is there a standard pattern for this approach? My initial thoughts are to

1. Where possible, Azure Data Factory to migrate data into Azure Data Lake.
2. Where this isn't possible, automate the extract and dump of data into Azure Data Lake.
3. User Power BI Desktop to connect to the csv datasets to generate a model & reports (whilst performing considerable transformation)
4. Publish to PowerBI Service to share amongst users

Concerns...

1. Should we be using DataFlows within Data Factory (or some other ETL) to do transformation OR continue using the Query Editor in PowerBI
2. Are there performance issues with connecting many datasets and performing considerable transformation activities within PowerBI Desktop?
3. In order to update the report with new data, is it just a case of overwriting the previous CSV file in the datalake and refreshing the report?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience:

1. Use Query Editor. That's the popular tool. Tons of examples & videos everywhere.
2. Not sure what "many" is, but you can load a spreadsheet file that's up to 1GB. A single worksheet can be up to 30MB. [Click here for more on limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/reduce-the-size-of-an-excel-workbook)
3. Yes. And you can also setup automatic refreshes so you don't have to click anything.